# Sending a file with RestClient request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stream, postman

I have a service in .Net Core which takes an IFormFile as a parameter. I would like to send the data from this IFormFile up to an Api. The code below is the auto generated code from postman which worked for my request. In the 'attachmentRequest.AddFile("file", file);' line, file is a string of the local path which postman uploaded the file from. What is the best way to send my IFormfile as the file sent? Do I use a stream and save the IFormfile to a location in .Net Core and pass that address?

```
          public async Task<bool> PostIssue(IFormFile file)
            {
            var client = new RestClient("https://sample/10000/attachments");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var attachmentRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            attachmentRequest.AddHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
            attachmentRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=");
            attachmentRequest.AddHeader("Cookie", "atlassian.xsrf.token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_lin");
            attachmentRequest.AddFile("file", file);
            IRestResponse attachmentResponse = client.Execute(attachmentRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(attachmentResponse.Content);

            if (attachmentResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the second method of `AddFile`:

```
  public IRestRequest AddFile (string name, byte [] bytes, string fileName, string contentType = null);
```

Convert the IFormFile file to `byte array` format instead of getting the path to transfer the file.

What you said is that uploading to the local using stream is indeed possible, but this is an extra action, you can directly operate IFormFile into byte form and transfer it to the API, as shown below:

```
 public async Task<bool> PostIssue(IFormFile file)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:50855/Users");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var attachmentRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            attachmentRequest.AddHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");
            attachmentRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=");
            attachmentRequest.AddHeader("Cookie", "atlassian.xsrf.token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_lin");

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                attachmentRequest.AddFile("filename",fileBytes, file.FileName);
            }
            IRestResponse attachmentResponse = client.Execute(attachmentRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(attachmentResponse.Content);
            if (attachmentResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Api:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> attachments()
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files["filename"]; //get the file
            //do something you want
            return Ok();
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Very clear answer, I was did not realize that there was an overload for the .AddFile() which took a byte array instead of URL. Thank you!